Cannot click on "allow extended dynamic range" in system preferences
I have a m1 max macbook pro. I'm not sure if this is a bug or a software compatibility issue, but whenever I view HDR content the screen windowserver takes up 100% cpu and the increase of brightness of whole screen along with the decrease of brightness for sdr white is not synchronized, resulting in very noticeable stutter / flashes.
While I try to research around the issue, I came up with this option that should disable EDR, so at least I won't get this performance issue on my studio display. However, when I click on the check box nothing happens - it's still checked. Does this suggest a bigger problem with my system? Is there a way to set this via the command line?
